# Eigenbasis and diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Any transformation $T:V \rightarrow V$ can be cast into a diagonal matrix if there are $n$ distinct eigen-values for $T$, now it is said that $T$ becomes a diagonal matrix w.r.t. eigen-basis, does this mean that both the input and output basis are the eigen-basis?

By input and output basis I mean the basis used for the input vector into the transformation and similarly for the output vector.

Comment: Yes indeed, just so.

Comment: I am unclear on what input and output vectors are.

Comment: @JonathanY. Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 3):

The short version: Yes, that is correct.

*The somewhat-longer version*:

If $\dim V=n$, and $T\in\mathrm{Hom}(V)$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1}^n$, since every eigenvalue $\alpha_j$ has a corresponding eigenvector $v_j$, and eigenvectors corresonding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent, we have a basis $B=\{v_j\}_{j=1}^n$ of eigenvectors. (This is what we actually need for your assertion.)

Then as you hinted in your question for every $v\in V$ one has a distinct representation $v = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j$, and we observe
$$Tv = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j Tv_j = \sum_{j=1}^n (a_j\alpha_j) v_j.$$
In other words, the matrix representing $T$ w.r.t. the basis $B$ is diagonal:
$$\left(Tv\right)_B = \left[\begin{matrix}
\alpha_1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & \alpha_2 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \dots & 0 & \alpha_n
\end{matrix}\right]\left(v\right)_B$$
(Note that we indeed use the coordinate vectors of $v,Tv$ w.r.t. the eigen basis $B$.)